# Get the Taxonomy-name instead Taxonomy-slug in Advanced Search Form on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, function, custom-taxonomy

i'm working on this tutorial called "How to Create an Advanced Search Form for WordPress" (http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/10/how-to-create-an-advanced-search-form-for-wordpress/) and it works perfect. But i have a problem trying to show the Taxonomy-name instead of the Taxonomy-slug in the first 'Option' selector.

I know the problem is here, in 'functions.php' but i don't know how to rewrite it to get what i want:

```
function buildSelect($tax){  
$terms = get_terms($tax);
$x = '<select name="'. $tax .'">';
$x .= '<option value="">'. ucfirst($tax) .'</option>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $x .= '<option value="' .$term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
}
$x .= '<select>';
return $x;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: what you have seems ok to me...

Comment: Yes, the code is ok, but in the 4th line I need to display the Taxonomy-name, not the slug. Because in spanish some words have accent and the slug doesn't show these characters.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); echo  $term->name;
```